# Vuetify v-container fluid isn't properly applied

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using Nuxt.js + Vuetify to style my site but having an issue. When I use v-container, contents are always fixed at a narrow range and it seems like 'fluid' is set at false. Could you tell me a way to fix this problem?

default.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app>
      <Header/>
        <v-content>
          <v-container fluid>
            <Nuxt/>
          </v-container>
        </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

club_top.vue (this will be inserted to )

```
<template>
<div>
<h2>Club top</h2>
  <v-card elevation="6" v-for="article of articles" :key="article.slug">
    <NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'blog-slug', params: { slug: article.slug } }">
      <div>
      <v-card-title>{{ article.title }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>{{ article.description }}</v-card-text>
      </div>
    </NuxtLink>
  </v-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Header/>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <Nuxt/>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

See more info [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#default-application-markup)